# Global Vars Between .html and .js

Tags: javascript, html, file, variables, global

I currently have code within "index.html", including script tags with JS in them. I want to make a web worker so things run smoothly, so I made a .js file. Unfortunately, I can't communicate variables between the two files; everything just returns as undefined.

**Does anybody know how to make a variable cross between the two files?**

I looked all over stack overflow and couldn't find anything, because others use window.varName, but window can not be used in a .js file.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Do you want the variable to be accessible by both JS script file?

Comment: By both the JS file and index.html

Comment: If the `.js` file is run with a Web Worker, you'll need to [post messages between the page and worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Sending_messages_to_and_from_a_shared_worker) to have them share values.

Comment: But I need the variables from my .html file to be used in .js .

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi Workers run in their own context detached from the page and aren't permitted direct access to variables in other contexts. You'll have to redeclare the variables within the worker and have the page post their values in a message (or multiple) for the worker to receive and assign.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski What would the syntax of this message be? By the way, thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible unless you use javascript DOM methods like `innerHTML` or `textContent`. You can also look into [Pug Templating Engine](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

```
var element = document.querySelector('.hello')
var text = element.textContent;
element.textContent = "Hello World";
```

Answer (score 1):

This article shows how to use postMessage to get content into and out of a WebWorker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#The_JavaScript_code